# Java ME SDK 3.2 (and 3.3, 3.0 as well) just won't start

Tags: java, mobile, emulation

When i try to launch it any way, Java ME just freezes. To be more specific, javaw.exe called by device-manager.exe seems to go into infinite loop, since not a single exception or error message is passed. Icon in tray appears, but its menu, instead of devices list, shows only one entry: Exit, which incidentally doesn't work. I can only shutdown it through task manager. And since device-manager is required for emulator, i can't work with it at all.
I tried versions 3.0,3.2,3.3 of Java ME SDK and this problem persists in each one. OS: Windows 7. JDK: 7u25.

I've tried each and every advice i found on the Internet and still can't get it working. Device-manager log shows that the problem starts upon calling "rmiRegistryPortFile".

```
[2013-07-02 19:20:53.070]  DEBUG - strap.BasicObjectConfiguration - Calling create on rmiRegistryPortFile
```

That's always the last entry in the log.

There was only one way i've managed to get it working - by installing and running it under Windows Virtual PC. Curious thing is, under VM it's working fine in the same very OS (freshly installed Windows 7). But unfortunately that didn't really give much on the cause of the bug, and that's not a solution :( I have to somehow get it working without VM.

I tried reinstalling Windows, that didn't help. Looked through javaw I/O in Process Monitor and compared it with working one. It looks like one of the application threads suddenly shuts down after reading file "rt.jar" (when loading "rmiRegistryPortFile" i guess?), whereas working javaw writes to log-file immediately after that. Windows logs got nothing on the subject: no permission issues, no errors or warnings at the time.
Tried modifying PATH variable to the dir with rmiregistry.exe, did not help. Network sockets are available. Changed DEP settings, same.

Could anyone please help? I've spent days on this bug already.

Comment: wow, you have just did everything, I think this is related to the network problems, try to disable the firewall and run the device manager as administrator mode

Comment: Did that. Nope, doesn't work. And if i try to turn on administrator mode for javaw.exe, it won't start at all.

Comment: I'm really sorry for both, I'm really wondering, and the last possibility I'm thinking is permission sets, maybe some permission has denied

Comment: Oh man, it started! I set javaw.exe to compatibility mode with Windows XP (higher versions didn't work), and it started without freezing. Still not working though - emulator windows is not showing and device list in the tray icon menu is empty. But after several days we're getting somewhere :) You're right, this MUST be some permission problems. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely a permission problem. Try to look if any folder related to Java is "READ ONLY".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Checked off entirely the read-only flag for JDK, ME SDK and all temporary folders in C:\Users. But no, once i switch off the compatibility mode, device-manager goes insane again. 
Well, anyway the problem is pretty much resolved. Emulator started working properly after rebooting PC since yesterday (even though tray menu is still empty). NetBeans successfully identified ME platform, compiles and runs code.

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message when trying to run midlets through the built-in emulator of the JavaME SDK 3.0, try disabling DEP for runMidlet.exe.
Data Execution Prevention (DEP) configuration can be found at the following place in Windows: Control Panel > System Security > System > Advanced system Settings > Advanced tab > Performance > Data Execution Prevention.

Add this file to the DEP exclusion list:

```
<javame-install-dir>\runtimes\cldc-hi-javafx\bin\runMidlet.exe
```

If things work for you now, complain loudly to Sun (now Oracle) that they need to make software without buffer overflows.

Personally I filed a bug-report against the JavaME SDK 3.0. You should do that too, or make your voice heard on the same bug-report that you're having this problem as well.

1. Freshly installed windows doesn't have msvcrtXX.dlls

   Go to folder `runtimes\\cdc-hi\\bin` and copy `Microsoft.VC80.CRT` into `runtimes\\cldc-hi-javafx\\bin`. This problem will be fixed over autoupdate soon.
2. Problem with localhost

   Please edit `<javamesdk_installdir>\\toolkit-lib\\modules\\bootstrap\\conf\\system.properties` and change
   `device-manager.object-registry.host=localhost`  to:  `device-manager.object-registry.host=127.0.0.1`
3. Port 1299 might be taken

   Please edit `<javamesdk_installdir>\\toolkit-lib\\modules\\bootstrap\\conf\\system.properties` and change
   `device-manager.object-registry.port=1299`  to:  `device-manager.object-registry.port=1999`
4. XP 64-bit

   Please use 32-bit version of JDK.
5. Firewall

   Make sure that firewall is not blocking communication on ports given in 3. Default port numbers are 1299 for windows and 1999 for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all those steps above to no avail, until I replaced my JDK jdk-8u117 with jdk-8u112 (**Must be 32 bit**) after reading this thread https://community.oracle.com/thread/4009110. I had to restart my machine after changing the Java version because it was not detecting right away after installation. I'm using Netbeans 7.4.